# How to select only available time and date for doctor appointment booking system in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, appointment

I have only one table named **appointment_master** in MySQL in which I store the booking date and time entered by the patient. Appointment time is fixed means patient can book an appointment every 10 minutes means if one patient has booked appointment at 10:00 AM then other can book at 10:10 AM and so on. Now if an appointment is booked at 10:00 AM and when other patient try to book an appointment the date and time slot option 10:00 AM should not be displayed to other patient in the form select option tag.

My table is as follows:

```
name   lastname age gender   email            phone_no   app_date    app_time   
ramesh  ahir    30  Male    rames@gmail.com   9824758745 2019-01-18  10:20:00   
jitesh  thacker 35  Male    jitesh@gmail.com  9824758745 2019-01-21  10:30:00
```

Comment: Which datatype are you using for the app_time?

Comment: i use time datatype in mysql

Comment: So, if a patient books at 10.00, another patient can't book at 11.00 - until someone books 10.50?

Comment: i have predefined time slot i.e. 10:00 AM 10:10, 10:20,10:30 and so on. now when 1 book at 10:00 AM then when 2nd patient try to book he can only see the time slot 10:10, 10:20 and so on and 10:00 should not be loaded in <select><option> tag

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following, very simplified example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS slots;

CREATE TABLE slots
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,slot VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE);;

INSERT INTO slots VALUES
(1,'Slot 1'),
(2,'Slot 2'),
(3,'Slot 3'),
(4,'Slot 4'),
(5,'Slot 5');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookings;

CREATE TABLE bookings
(booking_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT  NOT NULL
,slot_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO bookings VALUES
(1,101,3);
```

To show available slots, we can do something like this...

```
SELECT s.* 
  FROM slots s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookings b 
    ON b.slot_id = s.id 
 WHERE b.booking_id IS NULL;
+----+--------+
| id | slot   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Slot 1 |
|  2 | Slot 2 |
|  4 | Slot 4 |
|  5 | Slot 5 |
+----+--------+
```

...or this...

```
SELECT s.*
     , CASE WHEN b.booking_id IS NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END available 
  FROM slots s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookings b 
    ON b.slot_id = s.id;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | slot   | available |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Slot 1 | yes       |
|  2 | Slot 2 | yes       |
|  3 | Slot 3 | no        |
|  4 | Slot 4 | yes       |
|  5 | Slot 5 | yes       |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

To make sure two users can't book the same slot simultaneously, we can do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO bookings (user_id,slot_id) 
SELECT 102,1 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookings y 
    ON y.slot_id = 1 
 WHERE y.booking_id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM bookings;
+------------+---------+---------+
| booking_id | user_id | slot_id |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |     101 |       3 |
|          2 |     102 |       1 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

...which prevents another user booking the same slot...

```
INSERT INTO bookings (user_id,slot_id) 
SELECT 103,1 
  FROM (SELECT 1) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookings y 
    ON y.slot_id = 1 
 WHERE y.booking_id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM bookings;
+------------+---------+---------+
| booking_id | user_id | slot_id |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |     101 |       3 |
|          2 |     102 |       1 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Everything else can be handled in your application code (PHP).

Answer (score -1):

1. use the below query to get the last appointment time

   select max(app_time) from appointment_master;
2. Save this time in a PHP variable $date1 (or any name)
3. Save the new appointment time as $date2 variable
4. get the difference between the two variables
5. Use if condition to prevent the appointment if the time difference is less than 10 minutes

Comment: I  need to load only those time slots which is not previously selected by any other patient in php form's <select> <option> tag.. means when form is loaded and if 1st patient has already booked at 10:00 AM then when 2nd patient book then it shows only 10:10 Am , 10:20 AM  10:30 AM and so on in  <select> <option> tag. and it should not show 10:00 AM to 2nd patient.

Comment: @AMITLAKHANI then use the difference value (4th point in my answer) as the min attribute value in the options tag. Im not sure whether options or select tag supports min attribute, but please give it a try.